# Accessing a form in an Angular-UI uib-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

If you have a form in a `uib-tab`, how do you access it to (eg) validate the form?

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8hTccl5HAMJwUcHEtnLq?p=preview

When I try access `$scope.forminside` it's undefined (the form inside the uib-tab). But if I do the same with `$scope.formoutside` I get access to form validation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uib-tabset` has its own scope, so the `forminside` will be on the scope of the `uib-tabset`. If you use the controller-as notation, it will find the correct scope (the one of the controller):

```
<uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab 1">
    <form name="vm.forminside">
    </form>
</uib-tab>
```

See [this edited plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/th4ttAKAafQtJL67pZCw?p=preview).